# How to export an existing html5 game to an IOS game app

Tags: javascript, cordova, cocos2d-iphone, cross-platform

I have a game written in html5(mainly written in JavaScript), using cocos2d-html5 game engine;

Now I want to make it an IOS game app so I can submit it to apple app store,then users can download and install it on their iPhone or Ipad;

So, my question is, how could I export it to IOS?

I have already tried using PhoneGap-a good cross platform engine for apps-to wrap my game, but it is too too slow for game apps;

Did anyone have some ideas or experience about similar things? 
I will appreciate it so much if someone could share some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32970/how-to-make-a-cross-platform-game-with-cocos2d-javascript-tutorial-getting-started), it creates a simple HTML-5 game using cocos2d & after that it ports it to coco2d-iphone, so it runs natively using the JSBinding for Objective-C & you'll get the best performance.

Comment: Thanks for helping. JSBinding for cocos2d is not that perfect at this time and I had tried sometime before. In fact, I have found some better game engines ,such as CocoonJS, Ejecta, which were easier to export my game to IOS.

Comment: Heh, those would be my next suggestion :)